# Application Insights - how to use ISupportProperties in TelemetryInitializer

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a custom AI Telemetry Initializer. Recently, I have started getting a compiler warning, saying `Context.Properties` is obsolete:
"TelemetryContext.Properties is obsolete. Use GlobalProperties to set global level properties. For properties at item level, use ISupportProperties.Properties."

1. How do I do that? Use `ISupportProperties.Properties`?
2. I am logging the tenant Id, and deviceID, from claims in the principal, per request. Is that considered app global or a support property?

```html
    public class JsonTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly SystemOptions _systemOptions;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accessor">For accessing the http context</param>
        /// <param name="systemOptions">System options</param>
        public JsonTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, IOptions<SystemOptions> systemOptions)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = accessor;
            _systemOptions = systemOptions.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the custom telemetry initializer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="telemetry">Telemetry</param>
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                const string tenantId = "northstar_tenantid";
                if (!telemetry.Context.Properties.ContainsKey(tenantId))
                {
                    var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
                    telemetry.Context.Properties[tenantId] =
                        ClaimsHelper.GetClaim<int>(user, TokenNames.TenantId).ToString();

                    var userId = ClaimsHelper.GetClaim<int>(user, TokenNames.UserId).ToString();

                    telemetry.Context.Properties["northstar_userid"] = userId;
                    var deviceId = ClaimsHelper.GetClaim<string>(user, TokenNames.DeviceId);
                    if (deviceId != null)
                    {
                        telemetry.Context.Properties["northstar_deviceid"] = deviceId;
                    }

                    telemetry.Context.User.Id = userId;

                    var sessionId = ClaimsHelper.GetClaim<string>(user, TokenNames.SessionId);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
                    {
                        telemetry.Context.Session.Id = sessionId;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is some info here, but still not sure how to access the ISupportProperties: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/820

Answer (score 16):

> 1.How do I do that? Use ISupportProperties.Properties?

Just cast the `ITelemetry`  to `ISupportProperties`.

My example code as below:

```
  using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
  using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
  using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

  public class MyTelemetryInitializer:ITelemetryInitializer
  {

     public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
     {
          //cast ITelemetry to ISupportProperties
          ISupportProperties propTelemetry = (ISupportProperties)telemetry;

          if (!propTelemetry.Properties.ContainsKey("isuport_key"))
          {
              propTelemetry.Properties.Add("isuport_key", "isupport_value");
          }

      }
  }
```

Then after execution, the property is shown in azure portal, screenshot as below:
[image]

> 2.I am logging the tenant Id, and deviceID, from claims in the principal, per request. Is that considered app global or a support property?

As per my understanding, you can use support property(item level) since it's similar with you did previously using like this `telemetry.Context.Properties["northstar_deviceid"] = deviceId;`

Comment: That is one ugly ass cast. It's real shame you need one.

Comment: @vit, Hi vit, if you have some solution better, please share with us. But it's not good to say something in your comment above.

Comment: I understand I could express my disappointment in a more family friendly manner, but the point remains. The new API design forces us to do this cast and I don't know of a way around it.

Comment: @vit, I can understand you, the app insights team never provides some official doc about it. I'll submit a issue about this and if any feedback from them, I will let you know.

Comment: @vit, The link is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/300), you can add your comments for that.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, given initializers are run each time telemetry is sent and `ISupportProperties.Properties` is instance level, can't we do without the `Properties.ContainsKey(...)` check? (Let's assume the key is unique to the app - not used by Microsoft, not set globally,...)

Comment: @Funk, if I remember correctly, the initializers would be called more than once per each request. There is an issue about this, but need take some time to find it.

Comment: @Ivan That's right, the initializers will be called again for all telemetry during the request (each log, event,...), but the `ISupportProperties.Properties` dictionary sent through the initializer pipeline will always be empty at first. Please let me know about the issue if you find it.

Comment: It's preferable to use `telemetry as ISupportProperties` vs the cast (`(ISupportProperties)telemetry`). The cast will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the telemetry item doesn't implement the `ISupportProperties` interface; `as` returns null if the interface isn't implemented.

Comment: There is no need for this type cast. And it's super easy in C# 7+, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405303/201303

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and find this post.
They added documentation for adding properties to TelemetryContext.
Simply cast ITelemetry to RequestTelemetry.

```
public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
{
    var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
    
    if (requestTelemetry == null) return;

    requestTelemetry.Properties["customProp"] = "test";
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a cast, you could do a [type test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast)

For example, in C# 7+:

```cs
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is ISupportProperties telemetryWithProperties)
        {
            telemetryWithProperties.Properties["mykey"] = "test";
        }
    }
}
```